# Helidon SSL/TLS Config/Setup

Tags: helidon

Currently I know that I have to use this https://helidon.io/docs/latest/apidocs/io.helidon.common.pki/io/helidon/common/pki/KeyConfig.html
but not sure how to load that file or even how to attach the config to the actual server. Also, I'm loading some other special config like this:
`Server.builder().addApplication(ENDPOINT, Application.class).config(config).build().start();`

Is it ok to add that KeyConfig just like the existing config in the above line?
This because I'm are calling OCI public APIs and some of them required extra certifications, so the problem I have is this:
`Failed to read response from endpoint, I/O error. javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Please can you give me some pointers/examples on what to try?

I'm already using a trust store file but this is only used in the request object, maybe we need to add another trust store to the server level.

Answer (score 0):

This [example](https://helidon.io/docs/v3/#/config/io_helidon_webclient_WebClientConfiguration) shows how to configure TLS for the server.

You can set the following configuration in `src/main/resources/META-INF/microprofile-config.properties`:

```
server.tls.private-key.keystore.resource.path=/path/to/file
```

You can hard-code a default value in the config, and override it with an environment variable:

```bash
server_tls_private_key_keystore_resource_path=/path/to/file
```

---

Note that if you are making client requests and need to define a trust store with custom certificates, the above won't work. You'll need to either update the default trust store of your JDK installation, or use some client specific configuration.

---

If you are using Helidon WebClient or JAXRS Client with the Helidon Jersey Connector (`io.helidon.jersey:helidon-jersey-connector`) you can use same `.tls` configuration.

See the webclient configuration documentation [here](https://helidon.io/docs/v3/#/config/io_helidon_webclient_WebClientConfiguration).

If using the Helidon Jersey Connector you can pass the configuration like this:

```java
import io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfig;
import io.helidon.jersey.connector.HelidonProperties;
import jakarta.ws.rs.client.Client;
import jakarta.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.Config;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigProviderResolver;

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Config config = ConfigProviderResolver.instance().getConfig(); // or get it with @Inject
client.property(HelidonProperties.CONFIG, MpConfig.toHelidonConfig(config).get("client"));
```

---

You can also do it like this:

```java
import io.helidon.common.LazyValue;
import io.helidon.config.Config;
import io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfig;
import io.helidon.jersey.connector.HelidonProperties;

import jakarta.ws.rs.ConstrainedTo;
import jakarta.ws.rs.RuntimeType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.FeatureContext;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigProviderResolver;
import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.AutoDiscoverable;

@ConstrainedTo(RuntimeType.CLIENT)
public class HelidonConnectorConfigFeature implements AutoDiscoverable {

    private final LazyValue<Config> config = LazyValue.create(this::clientConfig);

    @Override
    public void configure(FeatureContext context) {
        context.property(HelidonProperties.CONFIG, config.get());
    }

    private Config clientConfig() {
        return MpConfig.toHelidonConfig(ConfigProviderResolver.instance().getConfig()).get("client");
    }
}
```

And add a file at `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.AutoDiscoverable` with the fully qualified name of the class above.